# Cant show the identity of user in label why

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Right I am setting the following varable in my code behind like so

```
        public string userName { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms" && Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsIdentity _identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
                string userData;
                _identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;

               userName = _identity.Name;

               this.DataBind();
            }
```

and in my label I am using the following

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMainName" runat="server"  Text='<%= this.userName %>'></asp:Label>
```

But Im just getting display the full function call in the site

[image]

Showing the debugging

[image]

Comment: Why don't you set the Text property of lblMainName in your code behind, just after: userName = _identity.Name;

Comment: its a cms so was trying make a vairabile avail for the end user to use through

Answer (score 0):

put lblMainName.Text = userName; just under the code where you are showing the username.

Or lblMainName.Text = _identity.name;

Comment: this does not solve my problem I am referenceing it a number of places so dont want to do for each label!

Comment: @kymberly is a little difficult to know what you want to do with it. i use the code in the master-page and it works perfect for me. maybe try session state

Comment: @kymberly: Think on AngularJS.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales your answer devietats from the requirements